# Do copula describe multivariate distributions more accurately than their moments?

Tags: distributions, density-function, joint-distribution, moments, copula

**Moments approach:**

A common way to characterize and describe the density (pdf) of a random variable is to only look at the mean and standard deviation ($\mu_1$, $\sigma_1$) of its pdf. This mentality is also extended to bivariate data where we rely on ($\mu_1$, $\sigma_1$) and ($\mu_2$, $\sigma_2$) to help us describe their joint empirical distribution by switching to vector notation: ($\boldsymbol\mu, \boldsymbol\Sigma$), where the *vector* of means and covariance matrix are now used.

**Copula approach:**

Can it be said that estimating the joint probability of two variables, $X$ and $Y$, with an empirical copula, is a more intricate way of describing their joint pdf *beyond* just their first two moments? Can it also be said that empirical copula are a more accurate method of estimating pdf's than higher-moment approaches?

Answer (score 1):

Well, a copula is just a different way to present the joint distribution.  From the copula and the marginals the joint distribution can be reconstructed **exactly** (by using Sklar's theorem.)

Moments is a different story, you cannot in general recontsruct the joint distribution **exactly** from any finite set of moments, sometimes you can get good approximations. So I don't really see the point of your comparison, the uses of moments and copulas are quite distinct.

Comment: Even though the copula allows the joint to be *theoretically* reconstructed exactly, how easy is it to do this *in practice* as number of variables in the joint distribution become ever larger? Do non-parametric (empirical) estimators fail compared to parametric copulas?